# Rebind Kendo Grid in MVC

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to rebind Kendo Grid on a button click after filtering data using the JavaScript below, but it is not working. What should I do?

**My HTML code using Kendo.Mvc.Dll:**

```
Html.Kendo().Grid<EquityStreet.Data.ESData.Proc_GetESManagersListAndFilterResult>().Name("GridESManager").BindTo(Model.ESManagersList).Columns(columns =>
 {
     columns.Bound(m => m.pkESManagerId).Template(@<input type="checkbox" id="@item.pkESManagerId" />).Title("").Width("2%");
     columns.Bound(m => m.pkESManagerId).Template(@<text> @item.FirstName @item.LastName</text>).Title("Name");
     columns.Bound(m => m.CompanyName).Title("Company");
     columns.Bound(m => m.MobileNo).Title("Phone Number");
     columns.Bound(m => m.ESManagerStatus).Template(@<text>@(item.ESManagerStatus == 1 ? "Active" : "Inactive")</text>).Title("Status");
     columns.Bound(m => m.pkESManagerId).Template(@<text> <a href="../Utilities/NewESManager?EId=@item.pkESManagerId" class="access_btn">
     </a><a href="../Utilities/NewESManager?EId=@item.pkESManagerId" class="notes_btn"></a><a href="../Utilities/NewESManager?EId=@item.pkESManagerId" class="edit_btn">
     </a><a href="../Utilities/NewESManager?EId=@item.pkESManagerId" class="delete_btn"></a>
            </text>).Title("Actions");
 }).ToolBar(tb =>
 {
     tb.Template("<div class='GridSearchHeader'><div style='float:left'><input type='button' value='Reset Pwd'><input type='button' value='Delete'></div><label>Filter: </label><input type='search' style='width: 230px' id='txtSearch'><select id='Status'><option value=-1>Select</option><option value=1>Active</option><option value=0>Inactive</option></select><input type='button' onclick='FilterList()' value='Go'><input type='button' value='Reset'></div>");
 }).Pageable()
                              )
```

**JavaScript:**

```
 $.post('@Url.Action("FilterESManagerList", "../../Utilities")', { Keyword: Search, UserStatus: status }, function (result) {
            var grid = $("#GridESManager").data("kendoGrid");
            grid.dataSource.data(result);
            grid.refresh();
            alert(grid);
        });
```

Comment: Can you please check the above link if it helps you.[Kendo UI DataSource Refresh][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459848/kendo-ui-datasource-refresh/21727407#21727407

Answer (score 2):

Calling `grid.dataSource.data(result)` should rebind the grid unless the `result` is not in the expected format.

Comment: result is in correct format. When i check it using firebug it says

grid.dataSource.data(result)- data is not a function

grid.dataSource.read()- read is not a function

I have tried it many times but not working & checked everything. 

When I tried 

grid.dataSource=result; 

It assined, but not rebind grid.
grid.dataSource.fetch()- fetch is not a function

Comment: Hi Atanas Korchev,

Can you please provide me your email so i can send you sample project?

Thanks

Comment: I have found the error. Error is i was not import <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")"></script> Now Filter & rebind is working fine, but another issue arises of Now Templates are not working. Do you have any alternative for it? 

It should work like telerik Grid.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks that when using ajax-binding, calling `grid.dataSource.fetch()` will trigger the read method defined in the datasource and rebind automatically.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#gridName").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.sync();
```