# Kendo UI viewmodel binding to radio buttons within grid

Tags: data-binding, mvvm, kendo-ui

I have a set of radio buttons binded to a viewmodel:

```
<input name="A_22" id="A_StatusCode_22_0" onchange="display(this, 22, 0);" type="radio" data-bind="checked: viewModel.A_List[0].A_Status" rowindex="0" sid="22" value="A"/>
<input name="A_22" id="A_StatusCode_22_1" onchange="display(this, 22, 0);" type="radio" data-bind="checked: viewModel.A_List[0].A_Status" rowindex="0" sid="22" value="A"/>
<input name="A_22" id="A_StatusCode_22_2" onchange="display(this, 22, 0);" type="radio" data-bind="checked: viewModel.A_List[0].A_Status" rowindex="0" sid="22" value="A"/>
```

This set of radio buttons appears on each row of the grid...so the next row is:

```
<input name="A_22" id="A_StatusCode_22_1" onchange="display(this, 22, 1);" type="radio" data-bind="checked: viewModel.A_List[1].A_Status" rowindex="0" sid="22" value="A"/>
```

..and so on

Part of the viewModel related to the radio buttons (as JSON):

```
..."A_List":[{"A_Status": null,......},{"A_Status": null,......},{"A_Status": null,......}....]
```

Simple enough...the page renders without any complains...however everytime I click on one of these radio buttons all the rest of binding datasources on other part of the page would disappear and the page looks totally weired...even if I commented out the "onchange" routine of the radio button it does not make any difference?  Any suggestions when I have done wrong here?

Happy to supply more info without revealing too much of data...it is work after all...
Thanks in advance.

WML

Comment: It would be much easier for us if you can show a running example that reproduces the problem. Would be possible showing it in JSFiddle or JSBin?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rebind Kendo Grid in MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452329/rebind-kendo-grid-in-mvc)