# Kendo ui datasource refresh?

Tags: kendo-ui, datasource

I have used kendo grids and charts fine and refreshed them with the following example code:

```
$("#Product").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
```

However, I have used the datasource just to provide some basic data in a different view, like in this example where it does not use the grid http://demos.kendoui.com/web/datasource/index.html

Is there a way to refresh this datasource in the same kind of way as the above code does for the grids and charts?

Thanks, Matt

Comment: I am not sure if I understand ? Can you explain bit more. `dataSource.read()` should do the job.

Answer (score 39):

It seems to be that only the data is read with `dataSource`, you need to refresh the grid also like this:

```
$("#Product").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
$("#Product").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
```

Comment: Thanks, but this gives "TypeError: $(...).data(...) is undefined" error. I also looked on many pages and tried different variations of this solution but still get the same error. Any idea?