# How do I refresh kendo grid when datasource is changed

Tags: kendo-grid

I have used kendo grids and charts fine and refreshed them with the following example code:

```
          $("#Product").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
```

How do I refresh kendo grid when datasource is changed without redrawing the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this gives you better answer
[Kendo ui datasource refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459848/kendo-ui-datasource-refresh/21727407#21727407) like

```
 $("#Product").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
 $("#Product").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
```