# Kendo Datasource refresh

Tags: jquery, asp.net, angularjs, kendo-ui

I am facing the same problem that i was going through in the previuos questions asked in stack overflow with no success answer, can anyone please guide me.
[Kendo ui datasource refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459848/kendo-ui-datasource-refresh)

I am using angular js to bind the grid, say i am showing column " jan2016, feb2016" these two cilumns shows perfectly, but when i go back and select one more month "mar2016", the grid doesnt refresh showing the mar2016

I used k-rebind, datasource.read(), datasource.refresh()... nothign works

Thanks in advance
Ram

Answer (score 1):

While Erick's answer will likely work, instead of destroying in recreating your kendo widget, first try doing

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").setDataSource(datasource)
```

It's much less code and it's a cleaner way of changing the datasource

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and struggled getting an answer from stack and kendo Forums, what I came up with was the following:

First I store the data source by saving the response object in new object

```
var DataSourceObj = new []; //some ajax response
```

Then I destroy the grid completely

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.destroy();
```

Then I reinitialize the grid and bind the DataSourceObj (Usually put it in function closure to bind it in mutliple places)

```
function initGrid(datasource) {
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        selectable: "row",
        allowCopy: true,
        columns: [
            { field: "productName" },
            { field: "category" }
        ],
        dataSource: datasource, // bind here
        pageable: {
            pageSize: 10
        }
    });
}

//call initGrid  and pass datasource
initGrid(DataSourceObj);
```

hope this works for you man :)